# Why does Windows 10 mDNS response handling take 10 seconds?

Tags: windows, mdns

I'm seeing this issue when trying to resolve mDNS names. For example I have a Raspberry PI on my network connected via Ethernet. And when I try and ping it via it's mDNS name Windows takes about 10 seconds just to resolve the name. However by using Wireshark I can confirm that the mDNS response packet takes just 1 millisecond to be received.

Then a whole 10 seconds passes before the result is returned to the ping application. That seems oddly specific. Like it's a timeout or something.

[Here is a video of it in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSlArK0hYUg)

I've removed some other applications that were competing for port 5353 (Motu Hardware mDNS responder) and rebooted.

I don't know how to further dig into this issue. Or even what service doing the actual lookup. But I'd like to know if there is a fix for this?

Edit: There is some nbns and llmnr at the end of the 10 seconds, ie when the name resolution is reported to ping. In terms of MDNS there is a request and response at the start, obviously and then also a duplicate at the end. Another request and response for the same name. Still not clear why it's waiting so long to report the response to the user. Windows also sends a DNS request but gets no response.

Edit2: Installing windows on different hardware DOESN'T fix it. Bought a new PC and the exact same thing happens. Specifically I haven't installed things like Wireshark or Vmware yet. Which I thought might affect things.

Comment: Is it actually taking 10 seconds to resolve something else instead? Filter for `dns || mdns || llmnr || nbns` (nbns _in particular_), on all interfaces not just this one.

Comment: I have a bunch of VMWare and other network interfaces normally enabled but even if I disable all of those and leave just one ethernet active it takes 10 seconds.

Comment: `netsh int ip reset` and `netsh winsock reset` cures all manner of network oddities :p

Comment: Those netsh commands haven't affected this issue though. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

it tries to resolve your "ip14.local" alias on several protocols. Are you online when pinging? If not, the ping command will get stuck waiting for the dns server response